# How can I trigger some action once the player is exiting the collider door area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to do two parts with the script:

1. When the player is exiting a door trigger action.
2. When the action is tirggered make the npc slowly rotating facing the player and start moving to the player.

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.Playables;

   public class SpaceshipCutscene : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public Transform player;
       public Transform npc;
       public float cutsceneDistance = 5f;
       public float speed;

   private bool moveNpc = false;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start()
   {

   }

   private void Update()
   {
       if (moveNpc)
       {
           float travel = Mathf.Abs(speed) * Time.deltaTime;

           Vector3 direction = (player.position - npc.position).normalized;
           Quaternion lookrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
           npc.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npc.rotation, lookrotation, Time.deltaTime * 5);
           Vector3 position = npc.position;
           position = Vector3.MoveTowards(position, player.position, travel);
           npc.position = position;
       }
   }

   private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
   {
       if (other.gameObject.name == "Horizontal_Doors_Kit")
           moveNpc = true;
   }
   }
   ```

It's never getting to the `moveNpc = true;` line.

The player have a Rigidbody.
In the screenshot it's the player inspector. The soldier is not the player !
The player is a first person.

The soldier should rotate slowly facing the player and start moving to the player when the player exit the door.

[image: Player inspector]

The script is attached to the Spaceship GameObject:

[image: Script]

The door have some childs and this is the one with the box collider:

[image: Door]

That's why in the script I'm checking against the Horizontal_Doors_Kit since this doors child have the box collider.

But it's never getting to the line:

```
moveNpc = true;
```

I used a break point on this line.

Comment: Can you debug the OnTriggerExit 'if' statement and check the value of the 'name' property?

Comment: @DanielMatthews The trigger is not working all it's not getting inside the the OnTriggerExit

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the gameObject you want to detect collision must have a RigidBody.

Comment: The problem is seems to be at least from my test is that the script with the OnTriggerExit must be attached to the player and not to some empty GameObject ( Spaceship ). Once the script is attached to the player the trigger is working. I thought that the OnTriggerExit can be trigger from any object but it was my mistake.

Comment: Please write up this comment as an answer, since you solved your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is seems to be at least from my test is that the script with the OnTriggerExit must be attached to the player and not to some empty GameObject ( Spaceship ). Once the script is attached to the player the trigger is working. I thought that the OnTriggerExit can be trigger from any object but it was my mistake.